# Apache Zeppelin giving error with spark on different machines

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I have a local spark cluster setup with one master and one slave machine. I installed Zeppelin on more machine and trying to run some commands from Zeppelin to spark master machine. For that I have created a spark interpreter with master as `spark://<ip>:7077`

When I run `sc` command

It gives this error

> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
>   at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
>   at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
>   at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579) at
>   org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:182) at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.ClientFactory.create(ClientFactory.java:51)
>   at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.ClientFactory.create(ClientFactory.java:37)
>   at
>   org.apache.commons.pool2.BasePooledObjectFactory.makeObject(BasePooledObjectFactory.java:60)
>   at
>   org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:861)
>   at
>   org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:435)
>   at
>   org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:363)
>   at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterProcess.getClient(RemoteInterpreterProcess.java:139)
>   at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.interpret(RemoteInterpreter.java:192)
>   at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:93)
>   at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:207)
>   at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:170) at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.RemoteScheduler$JobRunner.run(RemoteScheduler.java:304)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I can telnet port `7077` from zeppelin machine. Also this is my local vm machine so should not be issue with firewall, also disable all firewall.

Please let me know the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can go thorough the bug reported here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-305 .

Taking an excerpt from that bug

```
I faced the same issue when I try to use Spark 1.5.1 under the latest version (0.6.0) of Zeppelin.

Following Dongjoon Hyun's suggestion, I set ZEPPELIN_MEM as -Xmx4g (the same value as SPARK_DRIVER_MEMORY in spark/conf/spark-env.sh) in zeppelin/conf/zeppelin-env.sh

export ZEPPELIN_MEM=-Xmx4g

As a result, the java.net.ConnectException problem is solved. Thanks!
```

Comment: I tried this with this option export ZEPPELIN_MEM=-Xmx512m as my spark is 512 mb but still the same result

Comment: I have installed zepeline .5.5 on one machine and spark 1.4 is already installed on other machine. I added the export ZePPELIN_MEM in the env file still the same issue. Do I need to do anything on the spark machine. I can run my spark jobs through spark submit on the spark machine

Comment: spark with 512 MB seems less. Can you give me details of the system that you are trying to install upon. Have you done the basic configurations of setting the "Spark_Home" and master ip in the GUI for zepplin ?

Comment: yes I did. Now I have setup zeppelin and spark on the same machine and its working.